# Java Draw Shapes Error

Tags: java, applet

I have to write a program using applet it should have 3 Button line,rect,circle.Upon clicking on them the desired shape should be drawn.

I have written the following code but it is showing error that Graphics is not initialized.
What to do now?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Drawshapes extends Applet implements ActionListener
{

    Button line,rect,circle;
    public void init()
    {

        line=new Button("Line");

        rect=new Button("Rectangle");
        circle=new Button("Circle");

        add(line);
        add(circle);
        add(rect);

        line.addActionListener(this);
        rect.addActionListener(this);
        circle.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        Graphics g;
        if(ae.getSource()==line)
        {
            g.drawLine(0,100,100,10);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource()==rect)
            {
                g.drawRect(10,10,60,50);
            }
        else
        {
                g.drawOval(10,10,50,50);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all local variables, the `Graphics` `g` is required to be initialized. However, doing custom painting from the `ActionListener` is a bad idea. Use the `Graphics` object in the `paint` method which has been properly instantiated.

Set a flag in the `ActionListener` and then call `repaint`:

For example in `ActionListener` for line:

```
drawLine = true;
repaint();
```

*paint:*

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);
   if (drawLine) {
      g.drawLine(0, 100, 100, 10);
   } else if (drawRect) {
      g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
   } else {
      g.drawOval(10, 10, 50, 50);
   }
}
```

Comment: i have to display shapes on click events of button so i need to use ActionListener.How can i draw it using paint method?

Comment: Set a flag (preferably an `enum`) then call `repaint`. Described above

Comment: ok i understood man i will try this and thanks for showing the right pathway

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your `Graphics` reference.  You can initialize it by calling the [`getGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics%28%29) method that `Applet` inherits from `Component`.

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling methods from `g` which is not intialized as your error says : you have only declared it.

**Edit :** as others have said, your `Graphics` object is a member of `Applet`, and is accessible from the method `getGraphics`. Therefore you can call this method everytime you need it, or create a member in your `DrawShapes` class.

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getSource()==line)
    {
        g.drawLine(0,100,100,10);
    }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: hey man graphics is an abstract class how can we instantiate it?

Comment: Well, the question is about `g` being uninitialized, not about swing.